# iOS - retry mechanism

Tags: ios, swift, retry-logic

So I am trying to build a retry function for my network calls(first layer).
This is the function:

```
func retry<T>(_ attempts: Int, task: @escaping (_ success: @escaping (T) -> Void, _ failure: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Void, success: @escaping (T) -> Void, failure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    task({ (obj) in
        success(obj)
    }) { (error) in
        print("Error retry left \(attempts)")
        if attempts > 1 {
            self.retry(attempts - 1, task: task, success: success, failure: failure)
        } else {
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

the implementation is like so:

```
func refreshSession(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    cameraProtocols?.refreshSession( success: {
        print("calling serverping")
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.keepAlive(session: CameraManager.session, success: {
                print("serverping succsess")
                success()
            }, failure: { (error) in
                print(error)
                failure(error)
            })
        })
    }, failure: { (error) in
        print(error)
        failure(error)
    })
}

func keepAlive(session: String, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    cameraProtocols?.keepAlive(session: CameraManager.session, success: {
        print("server ping done!")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "pingSuccess"), object: nil)
        success()
    }, failure: { (error) in
        print(error)
        self.retry(3, task: { (success, failure) in
            self.refreshSession(success: success, failure: failure)
        }, success: { (success) in
            print("refresh succsed from retry")
            success
        }, failure: { (e) in
            print("refresh failed from retry: \(e)")
            //TODO - handle error logic when to procced with the failure closure
            failure(error)
        })
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "faildPing"), object: nil)
    })
}
```

When I fail the keepalive call on purpose the retry doesn't work as wanted and it wont stop ever.

Any suggestions for a new function or maybe how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have managed find the problem.
The retry func works fine but it repeats because i dont stop the timer in refreshSession so after 3 times it repeats.

Answer (score 2):

I think **CircuitBreaker Pattern** is what You need

The basic idea behind the circuit breaker is very simple. You wrap a protected function call in a circuit breaker object, which monitors for failures. Once the failures reach a certain threshold, the circuit breaker trips, and all further calls to the circuit breaker return with an error, without the protected call being made at all

see [this](https://github.com/fe9lix/CircuitBreaker)